# Swift swipe between table view cells?

Tags: swift, animation, tableview, delete-row

Currently, I have a `tableView` where each cell occupies the entire safe area, so the entire phone screen will be filled with the cell. However , rather than scrolling between the cells, how could I get it so that the users could Swipe Up/Down between the cells (no scrolling , just swiping up and down between the table view cell so one cell will come from the bottom and completely replace the cell on the screen)
I am using dequeable cells - I have tried turning off the scroll and using the cellWillload, however , I am not getting the desired results of swiping up and down between the cells.

Comment: 1: Just disable scrolling of tableview
2: Add swipe gesture on it
3: On gesture Trigger event manually scroll cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table view's delegate (probably your view controller), override `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` to set `targetContentOffset` so just one cell is visible.

Example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let targetRect = CGRect(origin: targetContentOffset.pointee, size: tableView.bounds.size)
        let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForRows(in: targetRect) ?? []
        let target: Int
        switch (indexPaths.count, velocity.y.sign) {
        case (0, _): return
        case (1, _): target = 0
        case (_, .plus): target = 1
        case (_, .minus): target = 0
        }
        targetContentOffset.pointee.y = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPaths[target]).origin.y - tableView.adjustedContentInset.top
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let desiredRowHeight = tableView.frame.size.height - tableView.adjustedContentInset.top - tableView.adjustedContentInset.bottom
        if tableView.rowHeight != desiredRowHeight {
            tableView.rowHeight = desiredRowHeight
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 20 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        return cell
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: demo]

Comment: So in this scenario, would I still have to use swipe gestures

Comment: No, you'd just let the table do its scrolling. But when the user lets go, you snap the scroll position so just one cell is fully displayed.

Comment: Since my rows are each a dequeable cell from a table view with an index path, how would I find the nearest multiple of the row height?

Comment: Does your table have a fixed row height, or do different rows have different heights?

Comment: it has a fixed row height of 100% of the table view height .